How to paste rich text from the clipboard in Python?
I'm trying to create a small program that can copy and paste rich text (bold, italics, etc...) from the clipboard to my application.
(OS: Windows 11) (Python version: 3.12)
I have installed the pyclip package (current version 0.7.0) which, according to the package documentation, supports both text and binary data from the clipboard.
I have written this test code following the instructions in the pyclip documentation:
import pyclip

data = pyclip.paste()
print(data)

pyclip.clear()

When I copy the following text from my email:

This is bold text in my email.

The screen result of the script is correct:

b'This is \xc2\xa0bold text\xc2\xa0 in my email.'

However, if I copy similar text from a Microsoft Word document:

"This is bold text in a Word document."

The result on the screen is not correct, the encoding does not appear:

b'This is bold text in a Word document.'

I understand that this is because Word does not use bold with ‘utf-8’ encoding. To retrieve the bold text information from the clipboard, you might need to directly access the Windows API. However, I am not familiar with the specific details of how to do this.
I have also tried with ctypes and win32clipboard with the same result following the advice in the thread How do I read text from the Windows clipboard in Python?
Thank you in advance!
